# How to make multiple pivot points on one object (BGE)

Tags: game-engine

This is a Tee shaped object to extend the pivot range of the arm on the left of the .png.
[image: Tee shaped linkage with three pivot points]

At the bottom link, where the 3D cursor is right now is the object origin and pivot point. How do the other two pivot points get...appointed?...to make the linkage work.
I've looked in the Blender manual, multiple videos on pivot points, vector groups, linkages, and more. I've considered adding separate objects and parenting them to the Tee object, but I'm sure there must be something better than that. Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you going for physics simulation or plain animation?

Comment: Physics simulation. I knew I could count on you, Monster!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For physics simulation I suggest to use rigid body joints.

You can have multiple of them at a single object.

[image]

[image]

Be aware

- at least one of the objects should be a physics object (rigid body, dynamic, soft body).
- the motions can exceed the joint limits (stretched chain).

Comment: ....the motions can exceed the joint limits (stretched chain) ............... I should be able to use a property or a constraint to limit the movement, right? Or doesn't that work with this setup?

Comment: I can't tell. It depends on your setup.